# How to model a ManyToOne and ManyToMany relationship on the same table in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I would like to create the following relationship between the tables

Tables -

- **Owner** - Owner table contains details about owner.
- **DietPlans** - DietPlans table contains all diet plans that can be created by the owner. A owner can create `n` number of diet plans but each diet plans belong to a single owner. Thus, it is a `1` to `n` relationship or One to many.
- **Customer** - Customer is basically an entity that consumes the diet plans. In other words, I want the customers to subscribe to the already existing diet plans. As such my understanding is that, this subscribing to a diet plan by a customer will be a Many to One relationship. `n` number of customers can subscribe to `n` number of diet plans and vice versa.
  The customer also has a Many to One relationship with the owner.

So, in order to realise this relationship I have 2 approaches. I would like to know which one would work better.

**Approach 1**
In this approach the `DietPlans` table will have `OneToMany` relationship with the `Owner` table and `ManyToMany` relationship with the Customer table.

`Owner` -

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OwnerKey ownerId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Customer> customers= new ArrayList<Customer>();


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Diet> dietPlans = new ArrayList<Diet>();
}
```

`Customer` table -

```
   @Data
    @Entity
    public class Customer{

        @EmbeddedId
        private CustomerKey customerId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional= false)
        private Owner owner;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "subscribedCustomers")
        private List<Diet> subscribedDietPlans = new ArrayList<Diet>();
    }
```

And the `Diet` plans would be as follows -

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Diet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(.....
    })
    private Owner owner;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn.....)
    })
    private List<Customer> subscribedCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

}
```

The customer should not be allowed to create any diet plans instead just subscribe to the diet plans **created by their owner**.

**Approach 2**
In this approach, instead of having the Many to many relationship between the dietPlans table and the Customer table, i will instead create a separate `SubscribedPlans` table which will contain reference (Foreign Key) from the `DietPlans` table. The `SubscribedPlans` table will have Many to One relationship with the Customer Table. In this way, the customer does not get to subscribe to a plan that does  not exist.

Which of the 2 is better in terms of simplicity ? Also, if there is a better way to do this modelling, please let me know.

Comment: Could you clarify this - Can one customer subscribe to multiple diet plans at the same time? or he can have one diet plan at a time?

Comment: Hi @YogeshBadke One customer can have multiple diet plans. And one diet plan can be subscribed by multiple customers. N:N relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question would depend on the answer to the following question

> Do you see an immediate requirement where you would need to put more
>   data against the user's subscribed plan? For example, say, the
>   duration for which subscribed plan will be active, pricing for the
>   plan etc.

If the answer is no, then you just need to maintain the mapping. In this case, approach 1 works better.

If the answer is yes, then you need to go with approach 2. Because `SubscribedPlan` entity will evolve and contain the user's subscribed plan related details such as duration, price (its going to be FK of price plan table) etc.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't Hibernate internally create a separate table for the Many to many mapping ? Can i not store the pricing , duration etc details in that generated table

Comment: If its simple M2M mapping containing only 2 columns, hibernate manages it automatically. If you want to have more columns, you need to manage it by yourself by making it separate entity.